# Prolog, list of digits to number, which one is faster?

Tags: list, numbers, prolog

So, let's say I have list `[1,2,3,4,5]` and I want get `12345` from this list.

here is code I wrote

```
l_to_n(L, N) :-
    reverse(L ,P),
    list_to_n(P,0,N).
list_to_n([H|T], C, N) :-
    C1 is C + 1,
    list_to_n(T, C1, P),
    N is H*(10**C) + P.
list_to_n([], _,0).
```

and here is something that I found

```
l_to_n(List, N) :-
    add_zero(List,Num),
    name(N,Num).

add_zero([X|Tail1],[Y|Tail2]) :-
    !,
    Y is X+48,
    add_zero(Tail1,Tail2).
add_zero([],[]) :-
    !.
```

Which one is faster/better to use for big lists?

Comment: Use rather `(^)/2` in place of `(**)/2`. In the standard and many implementations (IF, YAP, GNU, SICStus, Minerva, XSB, Ciao, IV) `**` produces always a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both ways are a bit *hacky*: in the first you first reverse your list, which takes *O(n)* time and, more importantly will require an additional *O(n)* memory to store the new list. Then you perform a recursive call without tail recursion while you need to keep track of the current position and perform an exponent operation. This can be optimized.

If I understand the second correctly, what you basically aim to do is converting the list of numbers to a list of ASCII characters. Then you expect name to do efficient parsing.

I propose the following predicate:

```
l_to_n(L,N) :-
    l_to_n(L,0,N).

l_to_n([H|T],A,N) :-
    !,
    B is A*10+H,
    l_to_n(T,B,N).
l_to_n(_,N,N).
```

It uses an accumulator `A`. For each element in the list, the accumulator is multiplied by `10` and the `H` (that number) is added to the accumulator. Next a tail recursion is done on the tail of the list. If one uses a smart compiler/interpreter the tail recursion will prevent building an *O(n)* call stack. This can be useful since you need to report the result back and undoing the call stack can result in additional computational overhead.

This predicate will however only work in one direction: list of digits to number.

**Demo**:

```
?- l_to_n([1,4,2,5],N).
N = 1425.

?- l_to_n([1,2,3,4,5],N).
N = 12345.
```

Answer (score 3):

Those 2 procedures are not comparable: the first computes a number, the second an atom. The second is clearly simpler, so will be presumably more efficient... if you have a builtin converting an atom to integer, of course...

The first can be optimized, instead of a multiplication *and* exponentiation, multiply by 10, getting the powers, and spare `10**C`.

In SWI-Prolog, `atomic_list_concat/2` can replace the second...